# Meshlabserver fails to convert .x3d

Tags: 3d, x3d, meshlab, stl-format

with most of conversions of MeshLabServer I'm getting this error:

```
meshlabserver: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/meshlab/plugins/libio_x3d.so: undefined symbol: gluNewTess
```

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10, I've tried to compile MeshLab for myself and use default package also.
How to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://sourceforge.net/p/meshlab/bugs/395/

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to convert X3D XML encoded files to VRML Classic encoded files you can use Titania, http://titania.create3000.de/. Open your .x3d file and save it as .x3dv or .wrl.

Titania also comes with a command line utitity »x3dtidy« that can do the conversion too. Simply type:

x3dtidy file.x3d converted.x3dv